# Same screen sizes but layout looks different

Tags: android, android-animation

I am using  Translate animation for moving a view to down. I have set the `android:toYDelta="65%p"`

And i run the application on 2 devices(`oneplus 2 and Nexus 5x`) which are having same resolution. `1080x1920`. But when the animation has done the layout animated differently.
Example: i have `textview` at the top of the layout, when i animate the `layout` it goes more down than the the `Nexus 5x on OP2`, even the screen size is same.

Thank you

Comment: what about device density ?  is it same each other too ?

Answer (score 0):

Both have same resolution but they have different dimensions OnePlus 2 has (5.98 x 2.95 x 0.39 in) while Nexus 5x has (5.79 x 2.86 x 0.31 in) thats why you are feeling difference

Comment: you will always feel a little bit difference in result because of its physical screen size.